# What is the shortcut for closing all of the open directory windows in nautilus?

Tags: gnome, nautilus

How can I close all the open Nautilus windows in one swoop? I'm using 10.10 and 10.04. I'll take anything -- keyboard shortcut, command line command, or mouse action.

Comment: Please elaborate further. Which system are you using? Unity or Ubuntu 10.10 or 10.04...Also do you mean keyboard shortcut/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Ctrl-Q should do what you ask.
(Ctrl-W will close one active tab or the window if there's only one.)

Comment: That will do it. Also did you set Nautilus to open every window in it's own? That can be reversed.

Comment: How? Please tell me :)

Comment: @wojox: I have "open every window in it's own" not checked, as by default. What do you mean by "that can be reversed"?